# Смена угла движения через стрелочки и движение в эту сторону Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, разработка-игр, canvas

Есть полный код того, что сейчас есть. Там реализовано движение ракеты за мышкой. Но сейчас нужно сделать так, чтобы кораблик всегда двигался вперед туда, куда он развернут, а уже стрелочками по чуть-чуть менялся угол его направления.

https://jsfiddle.net/8qgLxw5p/

```
(function() {
    const cnv = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    const ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");

    let mouse = new Vec2();
    let distanceVec = new Vec2();
    let myImg = new ImgSceneObject(
       new Image(),   
       'http://www.java-forums.org/attachments/java-2d/1449d1319003532t-tank-game-help-please-tankeast.jpg', 
       30, 30,
       new Vec2(200, 200)
    );
    let meteor = new ImgSceneObject(
        new Image(),   
        'meteor.png',
        50, 50
     );
    let angle = 0;
    let translationVec = new Vec2(myImg.pos.x, myImg.pos.y);
    let direction = new Vec2(); 
    let translationSpeed = 8;

    function initApp() {
      cnv.width = window.innerWidth;
      cnv.height = window.innerHeight;
      document.onmousemove = mousemove;
    }  

    function Vec2(x=0, y=0) {
      this.x = x; this.y = y; 

      this.add = function(v) {
        this.x += v.x;
        this.y += v.y;
        return this;
      }; 

      this.sub = function(v) {
        this.x -= v.x;
        this.y -= v.y;
        return this;
      }; 

      this.multScalar = function(s) {
        this.x *= s; this.y *= s;
        return this;
      }; 

      this.dot = function(v) {
        return this.x*v.x + this.y*v.y;
      }; 

      this.rotate = function(angle) {
        this.x = this.x*Math.cos(angle) - y*Math.sin(angle);
        this.y = this.x*Math.sin(angle) + y*Math.cos(angle);
        return this;
      }; 

      this.translate = function(v) {
        this.add(v);
        return this;
      };

      this.length = function() {
        return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y);
      };

      this.normalize = function() {
        const invLength = 1.0/this.length();
        this.x *= invLength;
        this.y *= invLength;
        return this;
      };
    }    

    function ImgSceneObject(img, src, w, h, imageCenter) {
      loaded = false;
      img.onload = function() { loaded = true; }
      img.src = src;
      this.pos = imageCenter;
      this.w = w;
      this.h = h;    
      this.update = function(angle, v) {    
        ctx.save();           
        ctx.translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y); 
        ctx.rotate(angle);     
        this.pos.x = v.x;
        this.pos.y = v.y;      
        if (loaded) {      
            ctx.drawImage(img, -this.w/2,  -this.h/2, this.w, this.h);
        }
        ctx.restore();
      };
    }

    function updateScene() {
      myImg.update(angle, translationVec);
      distanceVec.x = mouse.x - myImg.pos.x;
      distanceVec.y = mouse.y - myImg.pos.y;
      if (distanceVec.length() > 10) {
          translationVec.add(direction);  
      }
    } 


    function gameloop() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
      updateScene();
      id = requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
    } 

    function mousemove(e) {  
        mouse.x = e.clientX;
      mouse.y = e.clientY;    
      direction.x = mouse.x;
      direction.y = mouse.y;  
      angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y-myImg.pos.y, mouse.x-myImg.pos.x);
      direction.sub(myImg.pos).normalize().multScalar(translationSpeed);
    };

    initApp();
    gameloop();
  }());
```

Comment: Какая ракета? Какой кораблик? Вроде танк бегает за указателем. Этот код имеет отношение к вопросу? Надо похожее сделать, но с управлением клавиш со стрелками? Движение всегда сохраняется?

Comment: Упсс, ракета = кораблик = танк) Вообще я делал управление стрелками и нашел вот этот код, чтобы следовало за мышкой. Проблема в том, чтобы с помощью стрелочек менять поворот танка (по чуть-чуть, а не по 45 градусов) и чтобы он циклично следовал в ту сторону, куда он повернут.

Answer (score 4):

Самому проще написать, а потом усложнять если надо. Управление `D` и `A`. Можно добавить изменение скорости таким же образом для `W` и `S` для свойства `speed` только.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

playGame();

window.onresize = playGame;

function playGame(){
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  let w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
  let h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
  
  let x = 50;
  let y = 50;
  let angle = 0;
  let speed = 1;
  let rotateSpeed = 2;

  const image = new Image();
  image.src = 'http://www.java-forums.org/attachments/java-2d/1449d1319003532t-tank-game-help-please-tankeast.jpg';

  image.onload = render;

  document.onkeypress = changeAngle;

  function changeAngle(e){
    let sign = 0;
    if(e.key == 'd' || e.key == 'в'){
      sign = 1;
    } else if(e.key == 'a' || e.key == 'ф'){
      sign = -1;
    }
    angle += sign * rotateSpeed;
  }

  function render(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI/180*angle);
    ctx.drawImage(image, -20, -20, 40, 40);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  function move(){
    x += Math.cos(Math.PI/180*angle) * speed;
    y += Math.sin(Math.PI/180*angle) * speed;
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame(move);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(move);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="background: #eee"></canvas>
```

**Это с добавлением некоторых опций:**

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

playGame();

window.onresize = playGame;

function playGame(){
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  let w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
  let h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
  
  let x = 50;
  let y = 50;
  let angle = 0;
  let speed = 1;
  let rotateSpeed = 2;
  let acceleration = 0.1;

  let started = false;

  const image = new Image();
  image.src = 'http://www.java-forums.org/attachments/java-2d/1449d1319003532t-tank-game-help-please-tankeast.jpg';

  image.onload = render;

  document.onkeypress = changeMotion;

  function changeMotion(e){
    let angleSign = 0;
    let speedSign = 0;
    if(e.key == 'd' || e.key == 'в'){
      angleSign = 1;
    } else if(e.key == 'a' || e.key == 'ф'){
      angleSign = -1;
    } else if(e.key == 'w' || e.key == 'ц'){
      speedSign = 1;
      if(speed == 0){
        started = true;
      }
    } else if(e.key == 's' || e.key == 'ы'){
      speedSign = -1;
    }
    angle += angleSign * rotateSpeed;
    speed += speedSign * acceleration;
  }

  function render(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w, h);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI/180*angle);
    ctx.drawImage(image, -20, -20, 40, 40);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  function move(){
    pushX = 0;
    pushY = 0;
    if(x <= 20 || x >= w - 20 || y <= 20 || y >= h - 20){
      speed = 0;
      if(started){
        pushX = x > w/2 ? -1 : 1;
        pushY = y > h/2 ? -1 : 1;
      }
      started = false;
    }
    x += Math.cos(Math.PI/180*angle) * speed + pushX;
    y += Math.sin(Math.PI/180*angle) * speed + pushY;
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame(move);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(move);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="background: #eee"></canvas>
```

Comment: Для отлова событий клавиш кликните по внутренней области. Можно открыть на всю страницу.